# How can I sort my Linq list?

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, linq

This code snipplet works so far.

```
Dim newSource As List(Of Projekte) = source.Where(Function(a) a.parentId.Equals(parentID)).ToList()
```

But how can I manage to have the list sorted? Where do I put an "order by" (or something else)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [OrderBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method

For example, if you want to fetch data equals to `ParentId` entered by the user and sort them by `Id` field, check this:

```
Dim sortedList = source.Where(Function(a) a.ParentId.Equals(parentID)).OrderBy(Function(x) x.Id).ToList()
```

For further information about sorting data, please see this: [Sorting data (msdn)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546145.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

More samples you'll find here:

[101 Samples (msdn)](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/LINQ-Sample-Queries-13a42a54)

[101 samples - Lambda style (nilzorblog)](http://linq101.nilzorblog.com/linq101-lambda.php)

Comment: Thank you, but in your sample I am missing the "Equals". I need the where clause with equals PLUS the orderBy. Could you please modify my code sniplet in that way?